# trigger('close') is not working lightbox_me with ajax html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have HTML content which is added into DOM when ajax is fired. and I want to close lightbox when success response but it is not closing.

```
$(document).on("click", ".enquiry_form_submit" ,function(){
  var str = $("form#new_enquiry").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/enquiries",
    data: str,
    success: function(data){
      $('#enquiry-form').trigger('close');
      alert("test");
      $('#enquiry-form-submitted-info').lightbox_me({
        centered: true, 
        closeClick: true,
        closeEsc:   false,
        onLoad: function() { 
          $("#enq-form_submit-info").html(data)
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return false
});
```

But `trigger('close')` is not working here

`enquiry_form` is lightbox

Comment: What is `enquiry-form`?

Comment: @tymeJV `enquiry_form` is lightbox div

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#enquiry-form').trigger('close');
```

you are trying to call close method of enquiry-form, which is wrong.

You have to call something like

```
$('.close').click();
```

if close link has class called close

Answer (score 0):

**How to close a jquery lightbox**

Go to the source of the guy who wrote it, there is a basic example there:

http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/

If you defined your lightbox like this:

```
$('#my_lightbox').lightbox_me({
      centered: true,
      onLoad: function() {
        //statements to configure how the lightbox looks
      }
});
```

Then you can close it like this:

```
$('#my_lightbox').on('click', function(){
  $('#my_lightbox').trigger('close');
});
```

So you are capturing the click event on the lightbox itself with jquery.  You are running a function on that event.  Then you are getting the id that the lightbox is on, then telling the lightbox to close itself.  You could hook this to any event.